# opening modal with in another using angular strap

Tags: angularjs

I have modal dialog and my requirement is to open another modal dialog inside the modal(button click)

### button inside modal dialog

```
<a id="info" data-animation="am-flip-x" href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="getAccountDetailsToDisplay()"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></a>
```

I am getting the response from server and need to show some customer related data inside the modal

### controller

```
$scope.accountInfo = response;       

var accountInformationModal = $modal({scope: $scope, template: '../views/outwardClearing/accountinformation.html', controller: this, show: false, backdrop: 'static'}); 
                accountInformationModal.$promise.then(accountInformationModal.show);
```

modal(template) is calling but i could not able to see the modal.

Comment: if possible can you create plunker or fiddle

Comment: yes.its working. i kept the moedal function in the same controller